# Windows 10 with working keyboard and touchpad on HP Pavilion Chromebook 14

Tags: windows-10, drivers, chromebook

I successfully installed windows 10 on my HP Pavilion Chromebook 14-c015dx and I tried most of the custom drivers for keyboard and touchpad for chromebooks from [coolstar](http://coolstar.org/chromebook/windows-install.html) by following the instructions but they didn't work.

How do i get them to work?

Or,

Anybody here with windows 10 running on HP Pavilion Chromebook 14 with keyboard and touchpad working? Please let me know how you did it.